# How can I tell which object my character is stepping on in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I'm starting to learn how to use Unity and I'm building a demo using Unity-chan, for now let's say I have two boxes which represent the floor, how can I tell which box is my character is stepping on?
and as a bonus I'd like to recover the texture from that box to see what is the dominant color in a meter radius around her

Comment: You can get started with Unity using one of their tutorials. Start with the "roll-a-ball" [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). It shows how to basic collision detection.

Comment: okay I feel stupid now, I have been thinking that collision happen when an object is inside another (yes it does seem dumb now) thank you

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE]. This does not seem to be a code related problem.  It's more of an issue you should take up with Unity product support.  Did you find the answer to your question in the tutorial? If so, please post the answer here.

Comment: actually the Collider solve my first issue but I thought I'd keep it open in case somebody knows how to solve the texture question

Comment: Create a new question for that. Don't ask multiple questions also I don't thin saying "Bonus"  and asking another question is a good idea.

Comment: okay thank you, I'll remove this question then since it was answered

Comment: Go ahead. Make sure to post your current collision code in your new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned Collider does solve this issue as it is unrelated to C# but more of a Unity 3d thing